# Serialization error when copying and pasting from a windows form control to a WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5

We have a serializable class the holds the data from the clipboard to pass from a windows from control to WPF control. This worked in framework 4.8 after converting to .Net 5 we now get the error:
Type 'System.RuntimeType' in Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is not marked as serializable.

This occurs in the Drop event handler in WPF on the line:

`var tClip = e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ClipboardDescriptor));`

Where 'e' is the System.Windows.DragEventArgs.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Support.Classes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ClipboardDescriptor.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class ClipboardDescriptor
    {
        private Guid id;
        private Guid parentDocumentID;
        private System.Type objtype;
        private TreeNode baseTreeNode;
        private string objname;

        public ClipboardDescriptor()
        {
            baseTreeNode = null;
        }

        public Guid ParentDocumentID
        {
            get { return(parentDocumentID); }
            set { parentDocumentID = value; }
        }

        public Guid ID
        {
            get { return(id); }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public System.Type ObjType
        {
            get { return(objtype); }
            set { objtype = value; }
        }

        public string ObjName
        {
            get { return(objname); }
            set { objname = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the treenode that this object is associated with
        /// </summary>
        public TreeNode BaseTreeNode
        {
            get { return(baseTreeNode); }
            set { baseTreeNode = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably because some of the propertie types differ in namespace between .net 4.8 and dotnet 5

Comment: It was the System.Type property and the TreeNode property.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fix. In this case luckily the TreeNode property was unnecessary and the TypeName property could be added so the Type could be retrieved from it.

```
using System;

namespace JMPT.Support.Classes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ClipboardDescriptor.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class ClipboardDescriptor
    {
        public Guid ParentDocumentID { get; set; }
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        [field: NonSerialized]
        public Type ObjType { get; set; }
        public string ObjName { get; set; }
        public string ObjTypeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```